# Reading local XML in Sencha / Phonegap app?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs

In my jQuery/Phonegap application I was reading the contents of local XML using this:

```
$.get('resources/metadata.xml', function(xml){
alert(xml);
},'text');
```

But how to do that in a Sencha/Phonegap application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to use the exact same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to parse an XML file ?

Check out the [`XML reader`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Xml) of Sencha Touch 2

Comment: No I want to read entire XML content as a string that I have to pass to my Phonegap plugin.